# Get all keys from Hashtable

Tags: c#

I know hot to retrieve values from Hashtable:

```
Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
hashTable.Add(1, "11");

Console.WriteLine("hashTable {0}", hashTable[1]);
```

But how to get all keys from Hashtable ?

Comment: `hashTable.Keys`? E.g. `Console.Write(string.Join(", ", hashTable.Keys.OfType<Object>()));`

Comment: `Hashtable.Keys`, easily googled. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.keys(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/hashtable) would be a better documentation for that. A lot of exemple around hashtable

Comment: Documentation answers very simple questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate through HashTable keys as:

```
foreach(object key in hashTable.Keys)
{
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", key, hashTable[key]));
}
```

Or you can also do as below:

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry entry in hashtable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + ":" + entry.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a `Keys` property which you can use to retrieve all keys of a `Hashtable` as an `ICollection`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.hashtable.keys(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
hashTable.Add(1, "11");

var keys = hashTable.Keys;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the [Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

By the way, unless you've got a good reason not to use it you really should be using the [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: @Dr.Snail - no, it's an answer to the question "how to get all the keys from Hashtable"

Comment: @Dr.Snail, It looks like an answer. As it's a property i think no code is needed to explain how to use it. It has a link to Msdn. Op show no meaning full use case of the key so their is no code implementing that usage to add in an answer. It add Extra information about Something like a hashtable, that have cool way to access key.

Comment: Well, it´s an answer, but a bad one. In particular it shows no additional value over the other answers.

Comment: ok so my downvote remains for the fact that it is a bad answer